# wpallimport - how do I replace sku with product id?

Tags: woocommerce, wpallimport

I use a feed from a manufacturer to upload to a WooCommerce custom field.
The custom field expects a product id as input, but the feed is not aware of this as it's created by WooCommerce.
I use SKU as the key to compare existing products with the feed.

The imported field is called {metaparent_sku[1]} and the content has several values separated by | , for example:
BDCD7 | BDAUX | BDCA1 | ADUP89
These are unique product sku’s referring to products already in WooCommerce.

What I’d like to do is replace the sku value with the corresponding product ID value in as it exists already in WooCommerce.

I’ve been trying to use str_replace but can’t figure out how to set it up, if that's possible at all. Or should I use lookup?
If anyone could help with some sample code I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the product ID by a sku field.

```
[wc_get_product_id_by_sku({sku[1]})]
```

So in your case that would be:

```
[wc_get_product_id_by_sku({metaparent_sku[1]})]
```

For when you have multiple sku's in one field make a custom function.
Place the following function in the [Function Editor](https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/developers/custom-code/inline-php/).

```
/**
 * Find product id(s) by sku(s)
 * @param string $sku
 * @return string with product id(s)
 */
function wp_all_import_get_product_ids_by_sku($sku, $seperator = "|") {
    // define empty $product_ids
    $product_ids = array();
    // remove spaces from sku
    $sku  = str_replace(" ", "", $sku);
    // convert to array
    $skus = explode($seperator, $sku);
    // find product ids
    foreach ($skus as $sku) {
        $product_ids[] = wc_get_product_id_by_sku($sku);
    }
    // return product ids
    return implode(" | ", $product_ids);
}
```

Then use it like this

```
[wp_all_import_get_product_ids_by_sku({metaparent_sku[1]})]
```

Comment: Sorry, a little too fast with my enthusiasm ;-)

It works only if there is one value in the imported field. If there is an array, the end result in the imported field looks like this example: 5358|5360|5424
So it basically imports the pipe (vertical bar) symbol as part of the value.
Does it have something to do with removing spaces from the sku? Without the spaces wpallimport apparently regards the pipe (|) as part of the value.
Perhaps spaces should be reintroduced after converting to an array?

Comment: So it needs to be 5358 | 5360 | 5424? I have updated my answer, does that work? 
On the return line you can change the seperator between product_ids.

Comment: Thanks, it works, really appreciate your quick help!

Comment: I still hit a snag when importing: Single data was accepted but when importing an array it would be imported by WP All Import but not be recognized as valid data by the plugin (Booster for WooCommerce). I checked with the developer what input the plugin expects, this is his answer:
_wcj_product_info_related_products_ids expect wordpress post meta array type. for example : a:2:{i:0;s:2:"100";i:1;s:2:"101";} 100, 101 are product id.
What would I need to do in the script to make the array import work?

Comment: Try replacing the return line with:
return maybe_serialize($product_ids);

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks again!!